# Updating defaultColumnDefs doesn't rerender the Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to add a button that toggles sorting in the grid, when I click on the button, and console log the defaultColumnDefs that sortable got toggled but the grid never rendered.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
function App() {

const [sort, setSort] = useState(false);

const [rowData] = useState([
  { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
  { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
  { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
]);

const [columnDefs] = useState([
  { field: 'make' },
  { field: 'model' },
  { field: 'price' },
]);

const [defaultColDef, setDefaultColDef] = useState({
  sortable: sort,
});

const sortHandler = () => {
  setDefaultColDef({ ...defaultColDef, sortable: !sort });
  setSort(prev => !prev);
};

console.log(defaultColDef);

return (
  <div>
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowData={rowData}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
    <button onClick={sortHandler}> {sort ? 'No sort' : 'Sort'} </button>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` property is stateful meaning that you can change them without having to update the column definition. To do this, you call the `columnApi` method `applyColumnState()`

See documentation on [Column State](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-state/)

Here is an [example that dynamically changes the sorting](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-state/#example-fine-grained-state) of the grid